# Telerik adding two cells from separate tables

Tags: c#, telerik

I have two separate tables in Telerik. Is it possible to add their contents together? The contents are two floating point values. This seems like it should be relatively simple (maybe it is), but I have not yet been successful in doing this. I've tried something like this `=(table1.Cell1.Value + table2.Cell1.Value)`, but it gives me an error saying the table cell values are not in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just making a new stored proc. which would gather the information I needed. I then created a new sql data source and used it in a separate table as a "Totals" tables. A very round-about way to get something that should/maybe is very simple. Anyways, it's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and could be done with Javascript on the client side.  On the server-side I would access the two data sources directly and databind to those the third control that is to receive the calculation output.

Let me know if you would like to discuss further